# Density of features from density of principal components

Tags: pca, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

I have used principal component analysis for dimensionality reduction on large number of features. But after some stack of unsupervised learning, I have calculated kernel densities for all these principal components which is needed for further analysis. These kernel densities make more sense/explainable when they get converted to original feature space than in the lower dimensional latent space.

Is it possible to *estimate* the densities of the features from the densities of principal components?

Let' say the number of original components is **n** and number of principal components is **m**. I am tempted to use the `PCA.components_` to estimate the density values in the original space(**n**). But the principal components(**m**) are calculated from the original raw data and not the density components of original raw data, which is holding me back.

PS: I have used `scikit learn` to compute the principal components.

Comment: Please clarify: as a first step you perform KDE of PCA of a large dataset -- correct? And is it also correct, that you then want to return from the transformed system to the original? It seems a bit strange, but maybe you actually want some kind of ranking of "importance" of the data? What do you want to do with the estimated densities? Regarding the central question, why the costly approximation (KDE) if you're interested in the pdf (or an estimation of it) in un-transformed feature space?

Comment: Sorry for missing those in the original post. I am doing density-based clustering on large data (in terms of no. of variables and dimensions). So, I have reduced the dimensions (PCA and robust scaling) and the algorithm computed both clusters and anomalies. My main objective is to analyze the clusters & anomalies to see why they happened and what features are important to clusters as well as anomalies(over time).

Comment: I am using KDE to understand the density of features in all the clusters and anomalies (over certain time intervals of interest) to rank the important features for cluster and anomaly formation respectively. But since the clusters are computed using PC's(Principal Component) and the estimated densities are in terms of PC's, I am trying to find a way to estimate feature densities from PC densities.

Comment: I am using support and density values from Univariate KDE to interpolate the densities at each value of PC (over all PC's). So the method is fairly quick. But is there another way to do it better or fast or another approach to my main objective of this problem ?

Comment: It seems that your actual problem is a lot more difficult than the original question. idk if there is a general rule, but reduction is the way to go if your input space is of high dimensionality. But usually it's the "price" one has to pay for simplification -- there is little to no "explainability" left. But it is not needed for the application of a tool chain. So -- in short, linear algebra allows you to express the original features as a linear composition of the PC. But this adds no "explainability" to the description. ( 2nd comment follows )

Comment: As I'd understand it, the key task is in describing and identifying changes over time. Clearly one needs to start with a description in order to have some "quantity" to evaluate. But pdfs (whether estimated or not) are intrinsically hard to compare. And secondly a change over time needs a completely different approach, unless you're only interested in a "did it change" - kind of indicator. But even this is hard work, if you want some statistical significance in the outcome. You would need to create a kind of reference (as you've already done), some means to describe its accuracy and create ...

Comment: ... a method of comparison that is credible within the accuracy and by this find the answer "it's the same" -- or not. A better approach might be to start with time series analysis, but this is a completely different field, The approach/method there needs to be chosen with some care. I have only little experience with that -- so I can't be giving real advice there. Maybe a new question emphasizing this topic can provide more help.